# Detect changed store in derived store with list of stores

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I have a derived store like:

```
const filter = derived([a, b, c, d, e], callback, null);

function callback([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e], set) {
  ....
  set(...);
  return() = {
    ....
  };
};
```

Is there an easy way to find out which store of [a..e] triggers the callback in the callback besides caching store values. For instance: I like to reset with set(null) if store 'c' updates.

Example code using a closure to cache a store value:

```
function cache() {
  let cached;
  return ([$a, $b, $c, $d, $e], set) => {
    ....
    set(...);
    return() = {
      if (cached !== $c.value) {
        cached = $c.value;
        set(null);
      };
    };
  };
};

function filterStore() {
  const callback = cache();
  const { subscribe } = derived([a, b, c, d, e], callback, null);
  return {
    subscribe,
  };
};

const filter = filterStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you would do that purely with a derived store, but when I hear *"tracing back what caused the mutation"*, my first thought is to look into actions (à la VueX/Mobx).

That means your derived store would effectively be a writable one, and you would write a service/action that updates all the stores accordingly :

```
const initMySecondStore =  writable(0)

const mutateCandSecondStore = () => {
  c.set(value)
  mySecondStore.set(null)
}

const mutateAandSecondStore = () => {
 c.set(value)
 mySecondStore.update(updateMeDifferently)
}
```

And then calling the actions accordingly in your UI.

I wouldn't use a derived store for something that does not purely depend on the state of other stores.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean and I'am not familiair with VueX. My derived store acts as a filter. But when the session changes (which is also a store) I have to reset the filter. The idea is: add the session store (c) to the filter, catch the session update and reset the filter.

Comment: And works fine. But to detect the c-store change I have to cache the last c-store value. My question: Maybe there is a easy and better way to detect which store changes in a derived store.

Comment: I meant that rather trying to detect if $c changes, you should use a specific function to update both $c and your second store (previously "derived"). This you are sure about what triggered the change. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: OK Etienne. I used a "specific function". But maybe it could be done within a derived store. A kind of auto reset on ... But I think there is no elagant solution, so I stick with the specific function.

Comment: Yep, that's a workaround but not really a proper solution to your specific question. Although I think, in the end it is more mainatable (at least it closer to common patterns)